# Program is not inserting into the database

Tags: php

My program doesn't insert into the database, tried various means, I'm new to php and tried to test myself with this but I'm finding it difficult to get. i think the problem is at the connection to the database but I'm not getting it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LIST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> TODO LIST </h1>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";

                try {
                    //create a database conneection 
                    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                    if(!$conn){
                        die("Database connection failed: ". mysql_error());
                    }
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (task, date, time) VALUES (:task, :date, :time)";
                    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute(array(':task'=>$task, 
                        ':date'=>$date,':time'=>$time));
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        ?>

        <form action = "todolist.php" method = "post">
          Task: <input type="text" name="task" id="task"><br/>
          Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="date"><br/>
          Time: <input type="time" name="time" id="time"><br/>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't select database http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

You are not select any database.
Try something like this.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Yourdatabasename");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to your database? You do not select any bdd and the logs are the right ones?

Maybe try:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");
```

At first, see if you are connected to your database

Comment: I have connected and i got a new error message 
execute(array(':task'=>$task, ':date'=>$date,':time'=>$time)); } catch(PDOException $e) { echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); } } ?>

Comment: It can not connect to your db. You are sure that the login is 'root' and the password 'empty' ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this way in one of my project. Create a **connect.php** file and create connection like this:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Yourdatabasename");
?>
```

Now in index.php file check if the submit button is pressed:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))

{

// include connection file
include("connect.php");

// get values
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["subject"]);
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["comment"]);

// Insert in database

$query = "INSERT INTO comments(comment_subject, comment_text)VALUES ('$subject', '$comment')";

mysqli_query($con, $query);

}

?>
```

Comment: "execute(array(':task'=>$task, ':date'=>$date,':time'=>$time)); } catch(PDOException $e) { echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage(); } } ?>"
This is the error message I'm getting now

Comment: I've given example in Mysqli and you are using PDO. Try mysqli if it works.